# Gluing Together Borel Measures

Tags: general-topology, analysis, measure-theory

Does anyone know a standard reference for the following, which I assume is true:

X a topological space, $\{U_i\}$ an open cover, $\mu_i$ a collection of regular Borel measures agreeing on overlaps. Then there's a regular Borel measure on X agreeing with the $\mu_i$.  If you want, assume X is a manifold.

Comment: On a manifold you could use a partition of unity...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh good point. And I guess regularity shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Come to think of it, I bet you can use a partition of unity on, say, a compact Hausdorff space... I bet.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: What if $X$ is not compact? How do you show the finiteness of your sum?

Comment: @AlexM.  Maybe I'm missing something, but I took David's comment to mean $\mu (f) := \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu_i(\phi_i f)$, for $\{\phi_i\}$ a partition of unity subordinate to $\{U_i\}$. Does that not work?

Comment: First of all, it is not clear from the statement of the problem that the index set of the cover is $\Bbb N$, in order for you to be able to sum over $i$. Next, who guarantees that the series that you wrote is convergent? Think of what happens when you try to define the integral of differential forms on manifolds: you do it first for forms supported in a coordinated chart, then with a partition of unity you globalize it for forms with *compact* support (but not with arbitrary support, because the defining sum would no longer necessarily converge). A similar argument applies here.

Comment: @AlexM. well I suppose if we're dealing with a manifold, there's a countable subcover, but I'm still not sure that's an issue. If f is compactly supported, only finitely many $\phi_i$ are nonzero on its support.  So the riesz representation theorem gives us $\mu$.. Right? Forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: If $f$ is compactly supported then everything is fine. The idea is that you need compactness somewhere, either in the function or in the underlying space.

Comment: @AlexM. I believe riesz rep says that any positive linear functional on the space of continuous compactly supported positive functions gives rise to a unique Borel measure.